# how to display separated name of app on iphone simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

I have one query regarding app name...actually is want to display the app name on simulator on menu page at that time i want to display the app name including space means my app name is "Demo iphone simple" like that and i want to display same in iphone menu screen not like "Demoiphonesimple" .

So can any one tell me what is the procedure for that..

Thanx & regards,
  Priyanka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change only displayed name....then

in your xcode project

go to `Resources > Demoiphonesimple.plist`

single click on it and in right side of `Bundle display name` write what you want to display....

`clean and run`...